# discord.js getting the avatar from a user data doesn't work

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to get a user data from a json file which his their data stored like this

```js
{
    "dq9": {
        "orderID": "dq9",
        "guildID": "808393863092764682",
        "guild": "Cat Club 1.6",
        "channelID": "826760001070039091",
        "order": "pizza pollo",
        "customer": {
            "id": "610915422723637268",
            "system": null,
            "locale": null,
            "flags": 128,
            "username": "GD GangstaCat",
            "bot": false,
            "discriminator": "4882",
            "avatar": "dc2f9c139e245e8f707a50e20bc6dace",
            "lastMessageChannelID": "826760001070039091",
            "createdTimestamp": 1565723987037,
            "defaultAvatarURL": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/2.png",
            "tag": "GD GangstaCat#4882",
            "avatarURL": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/610915422723637268/dc2f9c139e245e8f707a50e20bc6dace.webp",
            "displayAvatarURL": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/610915422723637268/dc2f9c139e245e8f707a50e20bc6dace.webp"
        },
}
```

now the command code

```js
let ticketID = args[0];

            fsn.readJSON("./orders.json").then((orderDB) => {
                const order = orderDB[ticketID];
                
                if(order === undefined) {
                    message.reply(`Couldn't find order \`${args[0]}\` Try again.`);

                    return;
                }

                const OrderEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('#FFFF33')
                .setTitle(`${order.customer.tag} (${order.customer.id})`)
                .setAuthor(`Order ID: ${args[0]}\nOrder status: ${order.status}`)
                .setThumbnail(order.customer.avatarURL())
                .setDescription(order.order)
                .setTimestamp()
                .setFooter(`From ${order.guild} (${order.guildID})`);
            
                message.channel.send(OrderEmbed);
```

doesn't work at all giving error `order.customer.avatarURL is not a function` others like `order.customer.tag` work well but the avatar one doesn't work any help?

Comment: It's not a function, so use `order.customer.avatarURL` instead of `order.customer.avatarURL()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the `()` from the end of `order.customer.avatarURL()`

```
           .setThumbnail(order.customer.avatarURL())
```

like so:

```
            .setThumbnail(order.customer.avatarURL)
```

`()` implies you're calling it as a function. it is not a function.